# .htaccess rewrite rule for string

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am writing a `Rewrite Rule` to get URL like http://hiccuptalks.in/matmatantera/kya-mo-di-bjp-2019-mai-350pahuchegi/41 and Rule is `matmatantera/([0-9a-z-]{3,50})/([0-9])$ matmatanter_answer.php?url=$1&id=$2 [L]` but when I am trying to access it on browser it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

CHange your RewriteRule as following:

```
RewriteRule ^matmatantera/([0-9a-z-]{3,50})/([0-9]+)$ matmatanter_answer.php?url=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

`[0-9]` will only match the numbers 0-9 once. The `+` tells to match the `[0-9]` expression once or more.

Test it on on: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/